# why can Arduino variables of int type contain a value such as A2

Tags: arduino-uno, variables

How come the following statement is true:

```cpp
int inputPin = A2;
```

I thought int variables can only hold integer numbers. Is the `A` just a representation of a number?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Normally, I'd vote to close this, as it's pretty simple and really language related and there's an endless pile of those questions.  But, I've seen *this* question come up countless times in conversation with new Arduino users in almost *exactly* this form, often citing `A0` instead.  So, I'm voting to leave it open.

Comment: It would probably be better written "following statement is **valid**" or something to that effect, as opposed to "true".

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. `A2` is just a number (like everything in a microcontroller). We can look at the corresponding part in `pins_arduino.h` (a file defined in the variants folder of your used core and of your used board, for me: `~/arduino-1.8.9/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/standard/pins_arduino.h`):

```
#define PIN_A0   (14)
#define PIN_A1   (15)
#define PIN_A2   (16)
#define PIN_A3   (17)
#define PIN_A4   (18)
#define PIN_A5   (19)
#define PIN_A6   (20)
#define PIN_A7   (21)

static const uint8_t A0 = PIN_A0;
static const uint8_t A1 = PIN_A1;
static const uint8_t A2 = PIN_A2;
static const uint8_t A3 = PIN_A3;
static const uint8_t A4 = PIN_A4;
static const uint8_t A5 = PIN_A5;
static const uint8_t A6 = PIN_A6;
static const uint8_t A7 = PIN_A7;
```

So here the core first defines the macro `PIN_A2` as 16 (which is the pin number of that pin) and then it declares a static constant `A2` with `PIN_A2`. So `A2` is just the pin number of that pin, `16` in this case.

This is done to make the code more readable. The analog pins are marked with `A0` to `A7`, so it is good to also be able to refer to that with these names. If you wanted, you could also use the pin number directly. But that wouldn't be as easy to read.

Comment: It makes no difference to the answer whatsoever, but I'm surprised you're using version 1.8.9.

Comment: I'm not using it very often, thus haven't really bothered in updating. But you are right, I should really do an update XD

Answer (score 0):

The value of the symbol 'A2' *is* an integer - it is an Arduino pin number. For an Uno, it is equal to 16. Are you maybe confusing the pin number, A2, with the value read from A/D channel 2? That would be the value returned by `analogRead(A2)` or `analogRead(PIN_A2)` as it has been #define'd. And even then, that value is also an integer between 0 and 1023, which represents the voltage on the pin, 0 representing 0v or Ground, and 1024 representing the reference voltage (therefore, 1023 represents any voltage that is greater or equal to ((1023/1024) * Vref).